# Using own typescript type definitions for a node module in VSCode

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm currently implementing twilio library in my project. Since the library does not have any type definitions available, I have written them myself in a file called twilio.d.ts and have put it in my main project. My current editor is VSCode and I'm not getting any sort of intellisense for twilio module.

If I put these definitions in the `node_modules/@types/twilio` folder with filename `index.d.ts`, it works. Is there some other way to tell the typescript compiler to include twilio.d.ts in the project and associate it with the twilio module?

Link to gist: https://gist.github.com/aksharpatel47/a1b40e61f5759d653187eebfce0c323b

My tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "es2015"
    ],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./custom",
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

My folder structure

```
- custom
  - twilio
    - index.d.ts
- node_modules
- index.ts
- package.json
- tsconfig.json
```

Comment: try [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html#types-typeroots-and-types), if works, I'll put it as an answer. Basically you need to add the folder with your typings to `typeRoots`

Comment: Hi Maximus, I tried adding the folder to typeRoots (["./node_modules/@types", "./custom-types"]). It doesn't pick up the custom twilio typings.

Comment: Does the `tsc` run successfully? If so, then it's a vscode configuration problem

Comment: Yes `tsc` runs successfully. But it does't catch any errors that I deliberately made to check if the type definitions are being considered.

Comment: how do you reference the library in your code? can you share the `index.d.ts`, I'll try locally

Comment: Heres the link to gist: https://gist.github.com/aksharpatel47/a1b40e61f5759d653187eebfce0c323b

Comment: something is wrong with your setup, it shouldn't work at all, you're using `export =` syntax and you should use `import TwilioLib = require("./custom/index");` instead of `import * as twilio from "twilio"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137413/discussion-between-akshar-patel-and-maximus).